# Telegram's instant view API: Element <img> is not supported in <p>

Tags: xpath, telegram, xpath-2.0, instant-view

I have problem when trying to create my Telegram's Instant View template, with this error:

```
Element <img> is not supported in <p>: <img src="mysrc" />
```

So, I decided to replace tag `<p>` if has `<img>` tag with `<figure>` tag

`@replace_tag(<figure>): $body//p//img`

But the result is not showing the image. FYI, the `<img>` doesn't have attributes except `src`.

Sample code:

```
<p><img src="mysrc"/></p>
```

I have no idea, please help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your code is it replaces the `<img>`.

Like what you've said, you want to replace `<p>` with `<figure>`. So replace the tag `<p>` with `<img>` children.

`@replace_tag(<figure>): $body//p[.//img]`

The more simple way is, `<figure>: $body//p[.//img]`

Comment: What if within the <figure> there are two <img> tags (i.e. for lazy loading)?

Answer (score 1):

I add the

```
@split_parent: //p/img
```

It works! Altough I don't know the reason...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).